# C# ASP.NET - Bind the properties of a property in a model

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I have a razor pages web app, where I want to bind all the properties of an already binded property of a model.

**The following works:**

In the page model:

```
[BindProperty]
public int[] Quantities { get; set; } = new int[3];
```

In the view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Quantities[0], new { id = "miniGlassQuantity" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Quantities[1], new { id = "glassQuantity" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Quantities[2], new { id = "bottleQuantity" })
```

**But when I refactor the array into a class with individual fields like the below, it doesn't work. It just refreshes the page when the form is submitted.**

```
public class Quantities {

    public int MiniGlass { get; set; }

    public int Glass { get; set; }

    public int Bottle { get; set; }
}
```

The new code in the page model:

```
[BindProperty]
public Quantities Quantities { get; set; } = new();
```

And how it is used in the view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Quantities.MiniGlass, new { id = "miniGlassQuantity" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Quantities.Glass, new { id = "glassQuantity" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Quantities.Bottle, new { id = "bottleQuantity" })
```

**EDIT:**
Here's how the quantity is being updated in JS:

```
let quantities = [0, 0, 0];
let allOptions = [
    "drinkOption--mini-glass",
    "drinkOption--glass",
    "drinkOption--bottle"
]
let allCounters = [
    "drinkOptionCounter--mini-glass",
    "drinkOptionCounter--glass",
    "drinkOptionCounter--bottle",
];
let allUnCounters = [
    "drinkOptionUncounter--mini-glass",
    "drinkOptionUncounter--glass",
    "drinkOptionUncounter--bottle",
];
let quantityElements = [
    "miniGlassQuantity",
    "glassQuantity",
    "bottleQuantity"
];
function hideElements(elements) {
    for (let elementId of elements)
        document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = "none";
}

function showElements(elements) {
    for (let elementId of elements)
        document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = "inline-block";
}

$(document).ready(() => {
    hideElements([...allCounters, ...allUnCounters]);

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $("#" + allOptions[i]).click(() => {
            quantities[i]++;
            console.log(quantities[i]);
            if (quantities[i] != 0)
                showElements([allCounters[i], allUnCounters[i]]);
            else
                hideElements([allCounters[i], allUnCounters[i]]);
            $("#" + allCounters[i]).text(quantities[i]);
            document.getElementById(quantityElements[i]).value = quantities[i];
        });
    
        $("#" + allUnCounters[i]).click(() => {      
            quantities[i] -= 2;
            $("#" + allCounters[i]).text(quantities[i]);
            document.getElementById(quantityElements[i]).value = quantities[i];
        });
    }
});
```

Somehow, this way of using the properties in the model doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks for reading through.

Comment: Hi @Abhinav, do you set breakpoint to the backend to check which method it hits and what is the `Quantities` value? What you want now is to get the hidden input value in the backend, right?  Pls share more code about how is your backend and frontend code like?

Comment: Hi @Rena, Yeah. I want the hidden input value in the backend. There are javascript handlers in the front end that set the value of the hidden input value on click. The cards look like this (my previous question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73176445/net-razor-pages-get-value-of-an-increment-counter

Comment: Hi @Abhinav, It seems your previous code is just increase the count, how do you set the value for the hidden input? You can F12 to check the Elements in the browser if the hidden inputs have value. Could you pls share the sample which can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Rena Just updated the question to include the JS

Comment: Hi @Abhinav, combine with your previous question, I know what is your `allOptions` and `allCounters`, but what is the `allUnCounters`? Ask again, have you F12 and check the Elements in the browser if the inputs set the value by js?

Comment: Oops... I later added a button to decrease the count. Like so: https://imgur.com/a/GYgoRYH

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246991/discussion-between-abhinav-and-rena).